# Left Join not matching where data exists - Temp Tabls SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that I am using to pull in data from different tables. I have broken downthe query into a few different parts to make like a little easier. The problem is that when an `ID` number exists for sure in both places the `LEFT JOIN` does not always match them up, somtimes it does sometimes it does not.

All of the `ID` numbers are of type `INT` so I know all the data types are the same. I tried to use `COLLATE SQL_Latin_General_Pref_CP1_CI_AS` in the join statement but that is invalid for data of type `INT` was the error I received. OK fine, but I am really stuck as I don't know where to proceede from here other than dumping into excel and doing a vlookup.

Here is what I have:

```
DECLARE @sd DATETIME;
DECLARE @ed DATETIME;

SET @sd = '2014-01-01';
SET @ed = '2015-10-01';

DECLARE @denials_write_offs TABLE (
    pk INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
    , pt_id               INT
    , bill_no             INT
    , denials             FLOAT
)
INSERT INTO @denials_write_offs
SELECT a.pt_id
, a.bill_no
, a.denials_woffs

FROM (
    SELECT CAST(pt_id AS INT) pt_id
    , CAST(bill_no AS INT) bill_no
    , SUM(tot_pay_adj_amt) AS denials_woffs

    FROM smsmir.mir_pay
    JOIN smsdss.c_Softmed_Denials_Detail_v 
    ON smsmir.mir_pay.pt_id = smsdss.c_Softmed_Denials_Detail_v.bill_no

    WHERE discharged >= @sd
    AND discharged < @ed
    AND LEFT(smsmir.mir_pay.pay_cd, 4) = '0974'

    GROUP BY pt_id
    , bill_no
) A

--------------------------------------

DECLARE @EDTBL TABLE (
    ACCOUNT INT
    , ED_MD VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @EDTBL
SELECT Z.*
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(ACCOUNT AS INT) ACCOUNT
    , ED_MD

    FROM SMSDSS.c_Wellsoft_Rpt_tbl
) Z

----------------------------------------

DECLARE @TmpDenialsTbl TABLE (
PK INT IDENTITY(1, 1)         PRIMARY KEY
, BILL_NO                     INT
     ...
     ...
     ...
 )

INSERT INTO @TmpDenialsTbl
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT bill_no
...
...
...
)
```

So as you can see, from the above every `pt_id` or `bill_no` is put into a table as an `INT` but I cannot for the life of me figure out why sometimes I get a match on my `LEFT JOIN` and why sometimes I do not. I did pull data from the `@EDMD` table and get the account number I was looking for but it did not hit on the left join below:

```
FROM @TmpDenialsTbl                       A
LEFT OUTER JOIN @denials_write_offs       D
ON A.bill_no = d.pt_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN @EDTBL                    C
ON C.Account = D.bill_no
LEFT OUTER JOIN @USERTBL                  F
ON A.CERM_RVWR_ID = F.login_id
    AND F.RN = 1
```

**Example of what I am doing and what I get back**

```
DECLARE @TmpDenials TABLE (
    PT_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @TmpDenials
SELECT A.*
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(PT_ID AS INT) PT_ID
    FROM SOME_TABLE
) A

DECLARE @EDMD TABLE (
    PT_ID INT
    EDMD VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @EDMD
SELECT B.*
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(PT_ID AS INT) PT_ID
    EDMD

    FROM SOME_OTHER_TABLE
)B

SELECT * FROM @TmpDenials
PT_ID     |
123456789 |

SELECT * FROM @EDMD
PT_ID     | ED_MD
123456789 | Dr. Emergency Room

SELECT *
FROM @TmpDenials      A
LEFT OUTER JOIN @EDMD B
ON A.PT_ID = B.PT_ID

A.PT_ID    | B.PT_ID    | ED MD
123456789  | NULL       | NULL
```

Comment: well, we can't actually see the inserts into both of those temp tables, so you are probably inserting data in one that you aren't inserting in the other

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example of some data that should match but doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem or not, but this condition is potentially suspicious:

```
FROM @TmpDenialsTbl A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     @denials_write_offs D
     ON A.bill_no = d.pt_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     @EDTBL C
     ON C.Account = D.bill_no LEFT OUTER JOIN
--------^
     @USERTBL F
     ON A.CERM_RVWR_ID = F.login_id AND F.RN = 1
```

If there is no match to the `C` table form `A`, then this will always fail to match.  I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior.

The other option is that a `WHERE` clause is filtering out the rows that you want.

Note:  When you use table aliases, you should use abbreviations for the table names, so `i`, `wo`, `e`, and `u` are better than the arbitrary letters `a`, `d`, `c`, and `f`.

Comment: The issue is that the data is there, for example pt_id 123456789 is in both @TmpDenialsTbl and in alias C (EDMD), when I do a SELECT from both of them separately the data shows in both tables, doing a left outer join fails to show it from EDMD. Does that make more sense?